# Thread issues with handler in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

One part of my activity needs two timers running at once, one of them using `Handler` and the other using `CountDownTimer`. The handler portion updates the display every second, while the `CountDownTimer` counts down to when this part of the code ends. For some reason, I cannot run these both at the same time, and even when I commented out the `CountDownTimer` portion, the handler portion only ran once, instead of repeating every second. I am at a loss for what to do here. Any ideas? The relevant part of the code is below. For some clarification, the first handler seen here is supposed to run on its own, until a condition is met, at which point it reruns the function and goes to the second `if` statement. Seen within the second `if` statement are the details I mentioned at the beginning.

```
private void statusCheck() {
    if (possible = true) {
        final Random random = new Random();
        final Handler handler1 = new Handler();
        final int delay1 = 1000; //milliseconds

        handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                runChance = random.nextInt(1000);
                if (runChance < 100) {
                    possible = false;
                    statusCheck();
                }
            }
        }, delay1);
    }
    if (possible = false) {
        final Handler Handler = new Handler();
        final int Delay = 1000; //milliseconds

        Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // code to update every second
            }
        }, Delay);

        new CountDownTimer(ghostDuration, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    //code to run when finished
                }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I only formatted your code. I didn't change it. Does this line of your code compile: `if (possible = true) {`

Comment: @Abra yeah, it all compiles fine, but the timers do not work like they're supposed to.

Comment: `if (possible = true)` Yes this does compile, but what is does is assigns `isPossible` to `true` and checks condition being `true` or `false`. Therefore your handler codes works and countdown does not.

Comment: @Hussain My handler code does not work, for some reason it only runs once instead of repeating every second like it's supposed to. This happens even when the countdown is commented out.

Comment: `Handler.postDelayed` runs after a `delay1` and stops. To keep it running every second you have tell the handler to do so inside `run`.

Comment: @Hussain thanks for the suggestion. What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's not a good idea to to run timer and tasks under Android that way.

Android will block these timer and tasks because they work against the framework.

If you want to implement it correctly with a WorkManager watch out this video from Google which gives you some fundamentals: [Android Jetpack WorkManager](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pe_yqM16hPQ)